# MySQL inner join issue selecting max row

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have some SQL below the problem I have is both leads (cosmic_leads) show with the same lead stage. I'm finding it hard to explain so I will post a SQL dump at the bottom so you can see table structures etc.

Here is the SQL:-

```
SELECT 
    cl.*, 
    clt.stage_name AS stagename, 
    cls.date AS moddate, 
    cls.time AS modtime, 
    cls.comments
FROM 
    cosmic_leads cl 
INNER JOIN 
    cosmic_leads_stages cls 
ON 
    cls.lead_id = cl.id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(id) as id 
    FROM cosmic_leads_stages 
    GROUP BY site, lead_id
) clsid
ON 
    cls.id = clsid.id
INNER JOIN 
    cosmic_leads_types clt
ON 
    clt.type = cl.type AND clt.site = cl.site AND clt.stage = cls.stage
WHERE 
    cls.date >= 20140701 AND cls.date <= 20140723
GROUP BY 
    cl.id, cl.site
ORDER BY 
    cls.date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Using this SQL I get the following:-

```
[
      {
        'modtime' => '145717',
        'sale' => '1',
        'name' => undef,
        'moddate' => '20140723',
        'comments' => undef,
        'username' => 'aap',
        'site' => '1',
        'handler' => undef,
        'stagename' => 'Closed - Success',
        'id' => 'lead1',
        'type' => 'Website'
      },
      {
        'modtime' => '145717',
        'sale' => '0',
        'name' => undef,
        'moddate' => '20140723',
        'comments' => undef,
        'username' => 'aap',
        'site' => '2',
        'handler' => undef,
        'stagename' => 'Closed - Success',
        'id' => 'lead1',
        'type' => 'Website'
      }
    ];
```

The stage name for lead1 on site 2 should read "New", can anyone see what the issue is?

Thanks

(SQL dump below)

--

### -- Table structure for table `cosmic_leads`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cosmic_leads` (
  `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
  `site` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(96) NOT NULL,
  `sale` varchar(48) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(96) DEFAULT NULL,
  `handler` varchar(96) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`site`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `cosmic_leads`

```
INSERT INTO `cosmic_leads` (`id`, `type`, `site`, `username`, `sale`, `name`, `handler`) VALUES
('lead1', 'Website', 1, 'aap', '1', NULL, NULL),
('lead1', 'Website', 2, 'aap', '0', NULL, NULL);
```

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `cosmic_leads_stages`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cosmic_leads_stages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `lead_id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `site` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `stage` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `time` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments_internal` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `extra` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `lead_id_site_stage` (`lead_id`,`site`,`stage`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `cosmic_leads_stages`

```
INSERT INTO `cosmic_leads_stages` (`id`, `lead_id`, `site`, `stage`, `date`, `time`, `comments`, `comments_internal`, `extra`) VALUES
(8, 'lead1', 1, 1, 20140723, 145701, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(9, 'lead1', 1, 9, 20140723, 145717, NULL, NULL, NULL),
(10, 'lead1', 2, 1, 20140723, 145724, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `cosmic_leads_types`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cosmic_leads_types` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `site` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `stage` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `stage_name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `type` (`type`,`site`,`stage`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `cosmic_leads_types`

```
INSERT INTO `cosmic_leads_types` (`id`, `type`, `site`, `stage`, `stage_name`, `status`, `amount`) VALUES
(4, 'Website', 1, 1, 'New', 1, '0.00'),
(5, 'Website', 1, 9, 'Closed - Success', 4, '0.00'),
(6, 'Website', 1, 10, 'Closed - Failed', 5, '0.00'),
(10, 'Website', 2, 1, 'New', 1, '0.00'),
(11, 'Website', 2, 9, 'Closed - Success', 4, '0.00'),
(12, 'Website', 2, 10, 'Closed - Failed', 5, '0.00');
```

--

### -- Constraints for dumped tables

--

### -- Constraints for table `cosmic_leads_stages`

```
ALTER TABLE `cosmic_leads_stages`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `cosmic_leads_stages_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`lead_id`, `site`) REFERENCES `cosmic_leads` (`id`, `site`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Your basic query brings back both the `closed -success` and `New` values, but you randomly exclude 2 of them with the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: I want to return the newest lead_stage value, why does site 2 return a closed - sucess value when it's not in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 cosmic_leads records, each of which have 3 records on cosmic_leads_stages.

Those 6 are joined to the max id of each site / lead_id from cosmic_leads_stages, bringing it down to 4 records. 2 for each record on cosmic_leads:-

```
ID      TYPE    SITE    USERNAME    SALE    NAME    HANDLER MODDATE     MODTIME COMMENTS    STAGE
lead1   Website 2       aap          0      (null)  (null)  20140723    145724  (null)      1
lead1   Website 1       aap          1      (null)  (null)  20140723    145724  (null)      1
lead1   Website 2       aap          0      (null)  (null)  20140723    145717  (null)      9
lead1   Website 1       aap          1      (null)  (null)  20140723    145717  (null)      9
```

You then join those 4 records against cosmic_leads_types based on type, site and stage and all 4 have a match, resulting in 4 records.

You then use `GROUP BY cl.id, cl.site` to reduce this to 1 records for each id / site. For each id / site it has found a match on *Closed - Success* and on *New* . The GROUP BY forces it to randomly pick one of these in each case (which one it choses is not defined).

As you current query goes it is producing what is to be expected.

However I think to get the results I think you want you need to include site in the join of *cosmic_leads* and *cosmic_leads_stages*

```
SELECT 
    cl.*, 
    clt.stage_name AS stagename, 
    cls.date AS moddate, 
    cls.time AS modtime, 
    cls.comments
FROM cosmic_leads cl 
INNER JOIN cosmic_leads_stages cls 
ON cls.lead_id = cl.id
AND cls.site = cl.site
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT MAX(id) as id, site, lead_id
    FROM cosmic_leads_stages 
    GROUP BY site, lead_id
) clsid
ON cls.id = clsid.id
AND cls.site = clsid.site
AND cls.lead_id = clsid.lead_id
INNER JOIN cosmic_leads_types clt
ON clt.type = cl.type AND clt.site = cl.site AND clt.stage = cls.stage
WHERE cls.date >= 20140701 AND cls.date <= 20140723
ORDER BY cls.date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Thank you, your explanation and SQL have helped me see where I was going wrong!